# Wordpress WP_Query search title only

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using WP_Query with "s" parameter, but it search all the fields in a post, and I only want to search the title in the post only. Not sure what is the proper way to do it?

```
$args = array(
    's' => $_POST['k'],
            'post_type' => 'my_post',
            "nopaging"=>true,
            'meta_query' => array(

            )
        );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: @user11877968, did you get it worked?

Answer (score 2):

We need to add filter to wordpress "posts_search".

Adding the following code to your active theme’s functions.php file will restrict WordPress search results to page and post titles only.

//Limit Search to Post Titles Only

```
function ni_search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
global $wpdb;
if ( empty( $search ) )
    return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
$q = $wp_query->query_vars;
$n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
$search =
$searchand = '';
foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
    $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
    $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
    $searchand = ' AND ';
}
if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
    $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
}
return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'ni_search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting thing. If you want to work this on products you should use `get_product_search_form` hook.

```
add_filter( 'get_product_search_form', 'ni_search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

In this way, the results should be given only from searching in Titles.